# Can't execute script into new tab in chrome extention API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to run `window.location.href= $newURL` after opening a new tab by using `executeScript`.

Error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?ie=UTF-8". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

What permission still needed to be added to this `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "declarativeContent", "*://*/*", "storage"],
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

and the running code for the new tab in `background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
   chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function( tab ){
     tab.url = "https://mahmoudzakaria90.github.io/HelloZeka/public/"
     chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: './inject.js'
     })
   })
   chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher()
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
 });
```

Comment: You should give more detail of what you are trying to achieve here. If you are trying to change the url you can use the chrome.tabs.update() https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update

Comment: It worked Thaaanx.

Comment: What I was trying to do is listening for a new tab created and re-direct this tab to my website, that's it.